# 301 redirect if url contains specific string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Didn't found in any of answers this, that's why I'm asking it.

Basically, I need to 301 redirect URL that contains some specific character in it, but dynamically.

Specific character is "/l/"

For example:

```
 - example.com/l/test should 301 redirect to example.com/test
 - example.com/test/1/2/l/3 should 301 redirect to example.com/test/1/2/3
```

Basically it means that any url containing "/l/" should be the same url, but without "/l/"

Restrictions:

```
 - /l/ can be anywhere in url.
 - url is dynamic
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*?/)l/(.*)$ $1$2
```

Comment: That's awesome. But minor question - right now, when i type example.com/l/test, it redirects to example.com//test ( two slashes ). Is it possible to get rid of one of them? Thank you!!

Comment: ok try my updated rule and test it by clearing your browser cache.